# Extend QDebug and suppress messages

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

We need to suppress qDebug() messages when tracing is disabled.
I know the `qInstallMessageHandler()` an we are using it but we need an additional `trace` method.

```cpp
class MyDebug : public QDebug {
  public:
    explicit MyDebug();
    MyDebug(const QDebug &o);
    MyDebug(const MyDebug &o);
    
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<QString> null_string;
    static void doDeleteLater(QString *obj);
};

MyDebug::MyDebug()
    : null_string(new QString(), &MyDebug::doDeleteLater), QDebug(null_string.get()) {
    qCritical("construct");
}

void MyDebug::doDeleteLater(QString *obj) {
    qCritical("delete");
}

MyDebug::MyDebug(const QDebug &o)
    : QDebug(o) {
    qCritical("called1");
}

MyDebug::MyDebug(const MyDebug &o)
    : null_string(o.null_string), QDebug(null_string.get()) {
    qCritical("called2");
}

MyDebug Application::trace(const uchar verbosity) const {
    MyDebug d = this->logLevel > 6 ? MyDebug(qDebug()) : MyDebug();

    // QDebug default verbosity is 2 - Range 0-7
    d.setVerbosity(qMin((uchar)7, verbosity));

    return d;
}
```

Now using the `Application::trace()` results in errors

```cpp
Application::trace() << QString("test");

...
construct
QTextStream: No device
delete
```

I thought it has to do with the lifetime of `null_string` when MyDebug is copied, but the copy constructor is never called.

Using a heap constructed `QString*` as QDebug device is working.

Answer (score 0):

Install a custom handler like:

```
#include <QtGlobal>

QtMessageHandler DEFAULT_MSG_HANDLER = 0;

void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    if (type == QtDebugMsg) {
        // Ignores debug.
        return;
    }
    // Redirects anything else to the default handler.
    (*DEFAULT_MSG_HANDLER)(type, context, msg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DEFAULT_MSG_HANDLER = qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // ...

    return app.exec();
}
```